# Tenant specific OAuth2 client for Google

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I looked at the OAuth2 support in Google - 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

I don't see a notion of tenancy. How do I register a tenant specific client? 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you say tenant, are you referring to a Google Apps for Work domain?  And when you say "tenant-specific client", do you mean that you'd like to restrict access to users in a particular domain?

In those cases, what you want is the `hd` param which is documented as part of the [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param) protocol (OpenID Connect is an identity layer on OAuth).

Specify the `hd` param on your auth request, and importantly [verify](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#validatinganidtoken) that the ID Token returned has a matching `hd` claim (to protect against client manipulation).